# AdonisJS Error: require() of ES Module yarn

Tags: hadoop-yarn

I have troubles width Adonis today and I hope you'll help me.

So I have node 18.18.0, yarn 1.22.19.
I upgraded all my packages with yarn upgrade -L.

When I launch the following command inside my project folder: "`yarn run dev`", I have this error:

```
Error: require() of ES Module
   C:\Users\user\Documents\AdonisJSTest\testyarn\node_modules\@adonisjs\repl\build\index.js
   from
   C:\Users\user\Documents\AdonisJSTest\testyarn\node_modules\@adonisjs\fold\node_modules\@poppinss\utils\build\src\esmRequire.js
   not supported.
   Instead change the require of index.js in
   C:\Users\user\Documents\AdonisJSTest\testyarn\node_modules\@adonisjs\fold\node_modules\@poppinss\utils\build\src\esmRequire.js
   to a dynamic import() which is available in all CommonJS modules.
```

So I went to the C:\Users\user\Documents\AdonisJSTest\testyarn\node_modules@adonisjs\fold\node_modules@poppinss\utils\build\src\esmRequire.js file and change the following line "return (0, esmResolver_1.esmResolver)(require(filePath));" to "return (0, esmResolver_1.esmResolver)(import(filePath));".

I relaunch the "yarn run dev" command and I got this error:

```
Error: Only URLs with a scheme in: file, data, and node are supported by the default ESM loader. On Windows, absolute paths must be valid file:// URLs. Received protocol
```

So I went back to the C:\Users\user\Documents\AdonisJSTest\testyarn\node_modules@adonisjs\fold\node_modules@poppinss\utils\build\src\esmRequire.js file and I tried to add "file:///" and the begining of the filePath variable as it's an absolute path but then I have a TypeError.

I search on the Internet some answers and I found some post on StackOverflow which had that kind of issue but I did't get it right.